# Batch file, For loop --processing with space(s) in the filename

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

**Example filename:**_*20230317003825_26_8_Channel 10*.mp4

The following example batch file will not process the complete filename. The filename gets delimited/truncated at the default 'space'. This behavior continues even when "delims==" or "delims=" is employed.

**Example Batch file:**

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /O *.mp4') do (
set f=%%i
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" !f!

)
```

**Failed results:**

*VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///V:/45011/Download%20Record/20230317/work/__20230317003825_26_8_Channel'. Check the log for details.*

When I employ either variation of "delims==", shown above, I get the added output failure:

*VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///V:/45011/Download%20Record/20230317/work/10_.mp4'. Check the log for details.*

I'm not looking for a work-around, I'm more interested in why this is not accepting space(s) as part of the original filename.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: You should use `"delims="` so that the entire filename is assigned to `%%i`. Preferably, to assign `%%i` to `f`, use `set "f=%%i"` which ensures any stray trailing spaces on the line are not included in the value assigned. Your `VLC` command is invoked with a space in the filename, so it sees the part before the space as one parameter and that after as a second. The cure is to quote the filename, so use `"!f!"` or `"%%i"` on the `VLC` line. Also, the `/o` is redundant since you haven't provided the order-by specifier.

Comment: @ Magoo, Thank you. Please allow me to hemorrhage my short comings. I stopped short of your 'working' resolve ("!f!"), for two main reasons: 1) I was brain-beat from playing musical chairs with using "delims=" or "delims==". For /? shows "delims==", various postings/threads use both "delims=" or "delims==". I'm still not sure if there's a difference between the two. 2) By time I thought of using ```"!f!"```, I had been so brain-beat, I talked/thought myself out of it, because I couldn't find any confirming documentation. I was just tired of failing

Comment: @ Magoo, finally, Your suggested ``` set "f=%%i"``` --I was thinking of a similar (incorrect) usage ( set f="%%i"). Hoping for the same outcome as your ```"!f!"``` (shown above), but I talked/thought myself out of the attempt. I am challenged by the help pages (/?). In this case I've learned over time to double quotes around strings with spaces. I have not found documentation that teaches and/or confirms, the same is true for double quoting var's ```"!f!"``` that contain strings with spaces. What did you read to learn this?